# Number of relations on A that are reflexive and symmetric but not transitive

Tags: combinatorics

Let A={v, w, x, y, z}

Determine the number of relations on A that are reflexive and symmetric but not transitive.

Attempt:

There are $2^{25}$ total relations. For transitivity, we are taking pairs like (a, a) (b, b) for granted and there are n of them, then there are $2^{25-5}=2^{20}$ relations which are transitive.

For symmetric, we have to pick subsets of 2 of the set A because then the partition {a,b} will give the relation both (a,b) and (b,a). There are $C(5,2)$ subsets of 2. Then there are $2^{C(5,2)}$ relations which are symmetric.

I'm stuck at transitivity. What I'm gonna do here?

Comment: You have a typo (I think): in the first para of your Attempt you mean "reflexivity" and then "reflexive" don't you?

Comment: Hint: the reflexive symmetric relations that *are* transitive are exactly the equivalence relations.

Comment: I don't understand the second para, the answer you get is the number of relations which are both reflexive and symmetric.

Comment: The equivalence relations are the partitions of the set, so enumerated by the Bell numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ohhhh! I get it now! Symmetric and reflexive relations also consists equivalence relations, so only thing we have to do is subtracting those! Thank you so much!