# number of relations that are reflexive and symmetric but not transitive

Tags: combinatorics, relations

I'm familiar with [Number of relations on A that are reflexive and symmetric but not transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740035/number-of-relations-on-a-that-are-reflexive-and-symmetric-but-not-transitive) but I'm not clear on how to close out the problem.

Let $S$ be a set with $5$ elements. How many relations on $S$ are reflexive and symmetric but not transitive?

---

I totally agree that relations that are all three are equivalence relations and are enumerated by the Bell number $B(5)$. So my thinking is that I'll add up all relations that are reflexive, $2^{20}$, and then add up all the relations that are symmetric, $2^{\binom{5}{2}}$, and then subtract $B(5)$. My problem with this though is that amidst the $2^{20}$ relations that are reflexive, some are ALSO symmetric, and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what else I need to subtract by.

Comment: A similar problem is that I don't know how to count the relations that are ONLY transitive. If I did then (call that number $A$) the answer is just $B(5)-A$.

Comment: After rereading the linked post, it seems $2^{\binom{5}{2}}$ is the number of relations that are (at least?) reflexive and symmetric. So then the answer is $2^{10}-B(5)=2^{10}-52$. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, $2^{10}-B(5)$ is correct, since $2^{n\choose 2}=$ the number of reflexive, symmetric, transitive relations $+$ the number of reflexive, symmetric, nontransitive relations, while $B(n)=$ the number of reflexive, symmetric, transitive relations, hence their difference counts what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Relation $R$ over $S$ is reflexive and symmetric when:$$\forall x{\in}S~.(\langle x,x\rangle{\in}R\wedge\forall y{\in} S~. (y\succ x\wedge \langle x,y\rangle{\in} R\to\langle y,x\rangle{\in} R))$$

That is to say, if we represent a relation as a $5\times 5$ grid with a check in every cell where the ordinates are in the relation, then the above will be true when every diagonal cell is checked, and a selection from the 10 cells in the upper triangle are check, as are the corresponding cells in the lower triangle.

So just count the ways to do this.